# Beginners book for .NET and C#? 

Tags: c#, .net

I want to do a project where I build a database-aware program with a front end using .NET with C#.

I am totally new to this language. Can anyone recommend a good resource? Perhaps an online PDF version of a book?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

there is some free books to begin with:

> **C#**
>
> - [.NET Book Zero: What the C or C++ Programmer Needs to Know About C# and the .NET Framework](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/index.html)
> - [Data Structures and
>     Algorithms with Object-Oriented Design Patterns in C#](http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus6/)
> - [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Answer (score 5):

This blog post has three good books used for teaching: http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/

Answer (score 4):

There are many awesome books for C# beginers. You can use ["HeadFirst C#"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449380344) or "Begining C#" to give a start. Once you get hands on practice on C#, then you can try ["Illustrated C# 2008"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599543) and/or ["Inside C#"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735616485) books. These books does not cover all the features of C#, but these will give you detailed description of features of C#.

Comment: +1 for Head First C# -awesome!!

Comment: "Beginning C#" may not be specific enough, there are quite a few books with a title starting by this.

Answer (score 2):

For C#:

1. [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632)
2. [C# in depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/) from [our own](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) nice guy.

Comment: I think CLR via C# is a bit difficult for beginners, but it is very useful book.

Answer (score 1):

Anything by Mike Murach & Associates, Inc. I have his books on JSP and Servlets, Sql Server, and Javascript.  These are some of the best programming books I have read.  Here is a link to his .NET books:

http://www.murach.com/books/vba.htm

If you are looking for free books, check out this link below; You have to sign up, its free.  There are probably thousands of books on various areas of IT, including programming.  Just use the search to find the books you are looking for:

"http://www.dbebooks.biz/"

Answer (score 0):

I have a few books that I still use now but basically I favour WROX, Apress and O'Reilly above anything else.

I used the 3.5 Version of [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/4-0-Nutshell-Definitive-Reference-OReilly/dp/0596800959/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336483583&sr=8-1) throughout Uni and found it to be a great resource, one of the best books I own.
The examples are very clear and easy to understand and it covers a lot of areas, also it is fairly compact and easy to shove in a bag to take with you which is a bonus compared to the WROX books.

I have [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Illustrated-2010-Experts-Voice-NET/dp/143023282X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1336483726&sr=1-1)  and find it useful even now when revising for job interviews etc, It explains a lot of the concepts of programming c# and whilst its not going to be much use if you want a book full of coding examples I still highly recommend getting it.

I also have the WROX Beginners / Pro C# 3.5 which I used a lot when I was at uni, the 4.0 version is out now ( [Here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Visual-2010-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470502266/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1336483874&sr=1-2) ) but you can probably pick up the 3.5 on Amazon marketplace quite cheaply. These books are like phonebook thick and great to have lying around as a reference.